# Inconsistency in Calculating Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points

Tags: mysql, cocoa-touch, swift, coordinates, cllocation

I have an inconsistency between calculations of distance with SQL consult, and `CLLocation`. How can I get the real distance?

Distance using this Swift code: 334.599618308747 km

```
var latitude = 19.395039;
var longitude = -99.156203;

    var fromLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude , longitude: self.longitude)
    var toLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeDestion , longitude: longitudeDestinaton)

    let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(toLocation)
```

Distance SQL :  207.91730456420444 km

```
SELECT id_gasolineria, 
   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(19.395039) ) * cos( radians( gasolinerias.latitud ) ) 
   * cos( radians(gasolinerias.longitud) - radians(-99.156203)) + sin(radians(19.395039)) 
   * sin( radians(gasolinerias.latitud)))) AS distance 
FROM gasolinerias 
ORDER BY distance;
```

How is the actual distance obtained using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (real) inconsistency. The leading factor in the
[Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
is the *earth radius*, and `3959` in your SQL formula is the (approximate)
radius in *miles*, therefore the result is 207.9 miles,
which is 334.6 kilometer.

If you replace `3959` with `6371` (approx.  earth radius in *kilometer*)
then you should get the same result as with your Swift code.